How to remove WordPress cloaking attack, possibly remove /page/ link
I am a newbie to WordPress websites, though I have some programming and development experience. On some WordPress websites that I have developed, on Google Search Console I see some links to random pages that are clearly not on my website - e.g. <mySiteUrl>/lotobar-igrovye-avtomaty-onlajn-v-besplatnom-rezhime-i-bez-registratsi/ - and for whom the referring page is <mySiteUrl>/page/<number>. However, when I browse to <mySiteUrl>/page/<number>, I don't find the random page link, and based on my research of various forums, it looks like my website might be undergoing a cloaking attack.
While the website appears to work fine, it does seem to cause problems for me in terms of SEO, since I have nearly 2,000 such random links in my Google Search Console, which can't be good for my SEO. Hence why I'd like to resolve the issue without having to recreate the website from scratch if possible.
I've used various security plugins to try and find and then fix the issue, including Wordfence, Sucuri, etc, but to no avail. I thought that maybe I could bypass this issue by not allowing WordPress to render /page/ links, but this is just a random idea I have; I don't know how successful it would be. I'm also open to other feedback and suggestions, any help would be appreciated.
